# How to count numbers between l and r divisible by k

Tags: python

```
# Taking inputs
l=input()  
r=input()  
k=input()  

count = 0
# For loop
for i in range(l,r):  
    if(i%k)==0:  
        count+=1
```

Comment: Assuming you're using Python 2.x (`input`), you're entering integers for your inputs, and you don't want to consider whether `r` is divisible by `k`, your code works just fine.  Just add a `print(count)` as your last line and you can see.  That being said, it's unclear whether this is a question or a statement.

Comment: Try this. `sum([i%k for i in range(l,r+1)])`

Comment: It worked, thanks man

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if r is divisable by k you would need to use `range(l,r+1)`. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range

Otherwise your code is ok.